# how to use cron job

Tags: cron

hope someone can show me how to use cron job. Ive logged into my control panel but I really could find out how to start from. Thanks for answering

Comment: What do you mean by "logged into my control panel"?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It depends on the UI you are using. Since you mention a control panel, you aren't using the standard one.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "how to use cron job"? Do you want a beginner's tutorial on cron or are do you want to know how to perform some specific scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good start for cron: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: References are good, but it's better to post here the relevant parts.

Comment: When the OP does not have any specific query, it seems OP needs a starting point only.